I get an error that these re-exported structures do not exist
I am a junior developer and I am getting an interesting error.
The error I get is as follows.

To elaborate, in the project I developed with React and Typescript, there is a core folder under the src directory and a hooks folder under it.
Of course, there are other folders under this folder.
We are interested in the table folder under hooks.
There are other folders under it.
Here is my folder construction.

This means that if I want to use a hook in the innermost folder, I have to export it outwards again and again.
The useTable file contains a hook and the types related to that hook. I export them all, but I get an error that the types are not there even though they are there?

As you can see the types are there and they are exported.
Is anyone else getting a similar error, how can I resolve this?
I could give up the idea of exporting these definitions over and over again all the way to the outermost folder, but I know that would not be right.

The word use has some kind of special meaning in React as it is used for naming hooks. Your issue is possibly the naming style you chose for your type names. By convention, TypeScript types should use pascal case for example useTableProps should be UseTableProps.
Additionally, avoid prefixing use to anything other than a hook in React.

I think your problem is in the names of the types. Try to rename the types as UseTableProps instead of useTableProps. I think it's getting confused because it starts with use word.
